# fopen() gives me malloc(): corrupted top size

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, fopen, binaryfiles

I am trying to write the contents of an array, to a binary file, but it gives the following errors when I run the file.

malloc(): corrupted top size
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define ONE 1
#define TWO 2
#define THREE 3
#define FOUR 4
#define FIVE 5
#define SIX 6
#define SEVEN 7

int getArrayLength();
void initializeArray(int *array, int length);
void printArray(int *array, int length);
void menu(int *array, int length);
void userChoice(int userInput, int *array, int length);
void serialSearch(int *array, int length, int givenNumber);
void quickSort(int *array, int start, int end);
int partition(int *array, int start, int end);
void substitute(int *firstElement, int *secondElement);
int binarySearch(int *array, int start, int end, int userChoice);
void arrayConcatenation(int *firstArray, int *secondArray, int *concatenatedArray, int length, int doubleLength);


int main() {
    int arrayLength = getArrayLength();
    int *randomNumbersArray = (int *) malloc(arrayLength * sizeof (int));
    initializeArray(randomNumbersArray, arrayLength);
    printArray(randomNumbersArray, arrayLength);
    menu(randomNumbersArray, arrayLength);

    return 0;
}

int getArrayLength()
{
    int size;
    cout<<"Please give the size of the array: ";
    cin>>size;
    return size;
}

void initializeArray(int *array, int length)
{
    srand(time(nullptr));
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        *(array + i) = 30 + rand() % 21;
}

void printArray(int *array, int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        cout<<*(array + i)<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

void menu(int *array, int length)
{
    int userInput;
    cout<<"             Array Functions"<<"\n"<<endl;
    do {
        cout<<"1. Serial Search"<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Array Classification"<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Binary Search (classifies the array automatically)"<<endl;
        cout<<"4. Concatenation of classified arrays"<<endl;
        cout<<"5. Print"<<endl;
        cout<<"6. Save and read array with binary file"<<endl;
        cout<<"7. Exit"<<"\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"Please enter your choice: ";
        cout<<endl;
        cin>>userInput;
        userChoice(userInput, array, length);
    } while (userInput != SEVEN);
}

void userChoice(int userInput, int *array, int length)
{
    FILE *myFile;
    int mergedLength = 2 * length;
    int *secondArray = (int *) malloc(length * sizeof (int));
    int *mergedArray = (int *) malloc(length * sizeof (int));
    initializeArray(secondArray, length);
    initializeArray(mergedArray, mergedLength);
    switch(userInput)
    {
        case ONE:
        {
            int givenNumber;
            serialSearch(array, length, givenNumber);
            break;
        }
        case TWO:
        {
            quickSort(array, 0, length-ONE);
            cout<<"This is the sorted array."<<endl;
            printArray(array, length);
            break;
        }
        case THREE:
        {
            int choice, existence;
            cout<<"What number you want?"<<endl;
            cin>>choice;
            quickSort(array, 0, length-ONE);
            existence = binarySearch(array, 0, length-ONE, choice);
            if (existence == -ONE)
                cout<<"The chosen number is not in the array."<<endl;
            else
                cout<<"The number is at index "<<existence<<"."<<endl;
            break;
        }
        case FOUR:
        {
            quickSort(array, 0, length-ONE);
            quickSort(secondArray, 0, length-ONE);
            arrayConcatenation(array, secondArray, mergedArray, length, mergedLength);
            quickSort(mergedArray, 0, mergedLength - ONE);
            cout<<"This is the first array in order"<<endl;
            printArray(array, length);
            cout<<"This is the second array in order."<<endl;
            printArray(secondArray, length);
            cout<<"This is the merged array in order."<<endl;
            printArray(mergedArray, mergedLength);
            myFile = fopen("binarydata.dat", "wb");
            if(myFile == NULL)
            {
                cout<<"Error in file opening."<<endl;
                exit(0);
            }
            fwrite(array, sizeof (int ), length, myFile);
            fclose(myFile);
            break;
        }
    }
    free(secondArray);
    free(mergedArray);
}

void serialSearch(int *array, int length, int givenNumber)
{
    int flag = -ONE;

    cout<<"Please give the number that you want to find in the array: ";
    cin>>givenNumber;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(*(array + i) == givenNumber)
        {
            cout<<"The number was found at position: "<<i<<"\n"<<endl;
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(flag == -1)
        cout<<"The number is not in the array."<<"\n"<<endl;
}

void quickSort(int *array, int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        int driver = partition(array, start, end);

        quickSort(array, start, driver-ONE);
        quickSort(array, driver+ONE, end);
    }
}

int partition(int *array, int start, int end)
{
    int key = *(array + end);
    int i = start - ONE;

    for(int j = start; j < end; j++)
    {
        if(*(array + j) <= key)
        {
            i++;
            substitute((array + i), (array + j));
        }
    }
    substitute((array +i + ONE), (array + end));

    return(i + ONE);
}

void substitute(int *firstElement, int *secondElement)
{
    int temp = *firstElement;
    *firstElement = *secondElement;
    *secondElement = temp;
}

int binarySearch(int *array, int start, int end, int userChoice)
{

    if(end >= start)
    {
        int middle = start + (end - start)/2;

        if(*(array + middle) == userChoice)
            return middle;

        if(*(array + middle) > userChoice)
            return binarySearch(array, start, middle-1, userChoice);

        return binarySearch(array, middle+1, end,userChoice);
    }

    return -1;
}

void arrayConcatenation(int *firstArray, int *secondArray, int *concatenatedArray, int length, int doubleLength)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        *(concatenatedArray + i) = *(firstArray + i);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        *(concatenatedArray + i + length) = *(secondArray + i);
}
```

The problem is in the case FOUR of the switch case part of the code.

Comment: Question: is there a reason you are using `malloc` and raw arrays in a C++ program?

Comment: Please don't use `malloc` in a C++ program unless you are also doing placement `new`.  Replace all your dynamically allocated memory with `std::vector` .  When  you use `randomNumbersArray` as an array you will invoke Undefined Behaviour; use `new[]` to allocate the memory.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp. 
Unfortunately yes. The reason is that my professor has requested so.

Comment: `int mergedLength = 2 * length;` but you only allocate `int *mergedArray = (int *) malloc(length * sizeof (int));` ??

Comment: If you put a `#ifdef TEMP_REMOVE` and `#endif` around all of the `case FOUR` code before `fopen()`, does the memory corruption still occur?  If not, I'd suspect that something in those functions is corrupting your heap, not `fopen()`.  The `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, and `fclose()` calls look okay AFAICT.

Comment: As well qsort, fwrite and fopen?

Comment: Btw this `#define FOUR 4` stuff is a bit silly... the point of avoiding magic numbers is to refer to numbers according to what they meaningfully represent, not just to spell the numbers out by their English names :)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  Thanks for noticing. I did not check that, and strangely the mergedArray was working just fine.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner So, it would be better to have it as

```
#define QUICKSORT 2
```

Comment: @FeanorNosselo yes, or better yet `enum {SERIALSEARCH, QUICKSORT, BINARYSEARCH, ...};` since `#defines` are considered inelegant.

Comment: @FeanorNosselo If you literally mean the number one, write `1`; if you literally mean the number two, write `2`; and so on. If you mean "any value that happens to be the value of 'one', be it 1, 2, 4, or 5092 – I don't care", a symbolic name makes sense. A `1` that means the number one is not a "magic number"; a `1` that means anything else is.